# Why is MPEG-DASH playback beginning at 2X my SegmentTemplate startNumber?

Tags: xml, streaming, media-player, playlist, mpeg-dash

I'm building a Dynamic Adaptive Streaming over HTTP (DASH) service. Here is the .mpd file it publishes:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<MPD xmlns="urn:mpeg:dash:schema:mpd:2011" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="urn:mpeg:dash:schema:mpd:2011 http://standards.iso.org/ittf/PubliclyAvailableStandards/MPEG-DASH_schema_files/DASH-MPD.xsd" profiles="urn:mpeg:dash:profile:isoff-live:2011" type="dynamic" minBufferTime="PT0S">
  <ProgramInformation>
    <Title>My Stream</Title>
    <Source>Music Inc</Source>
  </ProgramInformation>
  <Period>
    <AdaptationSet id="3" mimeType="audio/mp4" segmentAlignment="true" audioSamplingRate="48000.0" codecs="mp4a.40.2" startWithSAP="1" lang="eng">
      <AudioChannelConfiguration schemeIdUri="urn:mpeg:dash:23003:3:audio_channel_configuration:2011" id="2"/>
      <BaseURL></BaseURL>
      <SegmentTemplate initialization="mystream-$RepresentationID$-IS.mp4" media="mystream-$RepresentationID$-$Number$.m4s" startNumber="163428046" timescale="1" duration="10"/>
      <Representation id="128kbps" bandwidth="128000"/>
    </AdaptationSet>
  </Period>
</MPD>
```

However, when I open this stream (in VLC), I see 404 errors in the logs:

```
adaptive error: Failed reading https://************:443/mystream-128kbps-326856092.m4s: HTTP/1.1 404 Not Found
adaptive error: Failed reading https://************:443/mystream-128kbps-326856093.m4s: HTTP/1.1 404 Not Found
```

Note that the first segment template number that VLC attempts to locate is `326856092`, exactly 2X the expected number specified in the MPD by `startNumber="163428046"`

Comment: This doesn't exactly answer my question, but I've resolved the issue by adding `availabilityStartTime="1970-01-01T00:00:00Z"` to the MPD and `start="PT420289H50S"` to the Period.

Comment: Error 404 indicates a file is not found.  So it looks like the code is using files to playback MPEG.  The filenames that are being used are based on the size and offset of the MPEG data.

Comment: Segment filenames are sequential from starting number, afaik. Please point me to the part of the DASH spec pertaining to computing based on the size and offset of the MPEG data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all you created a `dynamic` manifest which means it's for a live stream.

When playing a live stream the player will not start with the first segment, it will try to determine the live edge based on the information you provided in the manifest. The live edge advances with the wall clock.

Since you didn't provide any kind of information like the `availabilityStartTime`, Period `start` etc. it uses just the time when the manifest was published - in your case the time of the HTTP response - and the segment duration.

For example:

```
publishTime = 1634310000

currentSegmentNumber = startNumber + publishTime * timescale / duration
                     = 163428046 + 1634310000 * 1 / 10
                     = 326859046
```

If for some reason your `startNumber` corresponds to the current Epoch time when you generate the manifest it'll try to start exactly at 2x.

Maybe you need a `static` VoD playlist if you want to start at the beginning of the content.

Read more here: [DASH-IF Timing Model](https://dashif-documents.azurewebsites.net/Guidelines-TimingModel/master/Guidelines-TimingModel.html)

Comment: Actually, you've nailed it! This is a live stream numbered from epoch. Thanks for the tips. I'm going to continue working through this, and likely accept your answer.

Comment: @CharneyKaye Then set the `availabilityStartTime` to the time the stream started, so 0 in the timeline corresponds to the first segment number. You should also include a `UTCTiming` element for clock synchronization.

Comment: sparing some implementation detailswhich are constrained by the nature of this project— is it okay to forever say that the stream started at 0 millis epoch, and the first segment number is nowEpochSeconds/10? So far, in my experiments this does seem to work. Please see my other question for context https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69590696/how-to-ffmpeg-encode-a-single-m4s-media-segment-for-use-in-an-fmp4-series